# bind parameter to pdo function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to write the below function to display the contents of a MySQL table.

```
$q=$_GET["q"];
function risk_allocation($db)  
  {    
    $result = $db->query("select r.risks as risks,r.risktype as risktype,j.job as job from risks r LEFT OUTER JOIN `jobsrisks` j on r.risks = j.risk and j.job=:q"); 
    $result ->bindParam(':q', $q, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    return $result; 
  }
        $allocationlist = risk_allocation($db);
```

I am then calling the finction with:

```
while($row = $allocationlist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
echo $line['risks'];
echo $line['risktype'];
}
```

I am receiving error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in /home/she/public_html/versionfour/getrisksperjob.php on line 11
```

where line 11 is

```
$result ->bindParam(':q', $q, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

I have the feeling this is a simple question resulting from me just being introduced to pdo, but any help appreciated as always.

**UPDATE**

as per proposed answers, my code is now as below to execute query and to include the variabe q. same error still occurs though. Thanks for help thus far, any ideas?

### Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in /home/she/public_html/versionfour/getrisksperjob.php on line 11

```
function risk_allocation($db,$q)  
  {    
    $result = $db->query("select r.risks as risks,r.risktype as risktype,j.job as job from risks r LEFT OUTER JOIN `jobsrisks` j on r.risks = j.risk and j.job=:q"); 
    $result ->bindParam(':q', $q, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->execute();
    return $result; 
  }
  $allocationlist = risk_allocation($db,$q);
```

Comment: You're still not preparing as suggested in the answer by JvdBerg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You `forgot to execute query`

```
$result->execute();
```

2.`$q` is `outside function so you will never get value of that inside function.` pass $q as second parameter of function

```
$q=$_GET["q"];
function risk_allocation($db,$q)  
  {    
    $result = $db->prepare("select r.risks as risks,r.risktype as risktype,j.job as job from risks r LEFT OUTER JOIN `jobsrisks` j on r.risks = j.risk and j.job=:q"); 
    $result ->bindParam(':q', $q, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result->execute();
    return $result; 
  }
  $allocationlist = risk_allocation($db,$q);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten to [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) the query, futhermore you need to prepare instead of calling query:

```
$result = $db->prepare("select r.risks as risks,r.risktype as risktype,j.job as job from risks r LEFT OUTER JOIN `jobsrisks` j on r.risks = j.risk and j.job=:q"); 
$result->bindParam(':q', $q, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result->execute();
```